# how to insert users, username in Hebrew language in wordpress programmatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, migration, hebrew

i am trying to insert users from my custom site, which is different language. Users have registered in that website either in english language or in hebrew.

using function  wp_insert_user

```
$usernicename = $userpost['first_name'] . $userpost['last_name'];
    $user_login_name = $userpost['last_name'].$userpost['first_name'];
    $user_password = "xyz@123";

    $userdata = array(
    'user_pass'             => $userpost['password'],   
    'user_login'            => $user_login_name,   
    'user_nicename'         => $usernicename,      
    'user_email'            => $userpost['email'],   
    'first_name'            => $userpost['first_name'],   
    'last_name'             => $userpost['last_name'],  
    'user_registered'       => $userpost['registration'],   
    'role'                  => 'subscriber',   
    );
$id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;
```

all users whose name are in english language get inserted successfully, But the users which are in hebrew/different language gives an error

```
object(WP_Error)#11230 (2) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["empty_user_login"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(46) "Cannot create a user with an empty login name."
    }
  }
  ["error_data"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I have changed the the site language from admin settings, but that also not worked.

Comment: Reading the error it just seem that you are missing some data in your $userpost variable

Comment: when i var_dump the $userdata, it shows the user_login value as well as user_nicename value. Also then in that case error should be in case of users having name in english language, but that not the case.

Comment: user_login in your data equals to $user_login_name which you declare as 
 $user_login_name = $userpost['last_name'].$userpost['first_name'];. So if for some reason your form in other lang doesn't have those fields / they are empty you will end with that error. I don't think that there should be any other issue language-related

Comment: array(8) { ["user_pass"]=> string(32) "23e91c69fc8046d49ddca39a4" ["user_login"]=> string(16) "ארציאיתי" ["user_nicename"]=> string(16) "איתיארצי" ["user_email"]=> string(23) "xyzi@yahoo.com .WP" ["first_name"]=> string(8) "איתי" ["last_name"]=> string(8) "ארצי" ["user_registered"]=> string(19) "2007-03-23 08:46:41" ["role"]=> string(10) "subscriber" }
object(WP_Error)#11229 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["empty_user_login"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(46) "Cannot create a user with an empty login name." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

above is the var_dump($userdata) & error

Comment: Maybe its the encoding then, something wp use to sanitize your input maybe stripping off the content. I can't help you more i guess, i'm not an expert with encodings :(

Answer (score 1):

i have found solution for my issue, it is happening mainy because of sanitization of username.
hebrew characters get santizied and it return null, that's why it gives an error empty login name.

this issue is resolved by using the code or wordpress plugin i have found

1.[wordpress special character](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-special-characters-in-usernames/)
2.[Hebrew Username](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/hebrew-username/)

Or you can use the below code and paste that in your function.php file , it will overide username santization function.

```
add_filter ('sanitize_user', 'hu_sanitize_user', 10, 3);

//Overrides the Wordpress sanitize_user filter to allow hebrew letters and english letters only

function hu_sanitize_user ($username, $raw_username, $strict)
{
//Strip HTML Tags
$username = wp_strip_all_tags ($raw_username);

//Remove Accents
$username = remove_accents ($username);

//Kill octets
$username = preg_replace ('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $username);


//Kill entities
$username = preg_replace ('/&.+?;/', '', $username);

if ($strict){
    //Replace
    $username = preg_replace( '[\p{Hebrew}a-zA-Z]', '', $username );
}

//Remove Whitespaces
$username = trim ($username);

// Consolidate contiguous Whitespaces
$username = preg_replace ('|\s+|', ' ', $username);

return $username;
}
```

Both of the above solution(code/plugin) will allow you to enter only 8 Hebrew characters in username. this is because as user_login column is declared as varchar(60) and hebrew character take more bytes as compared to english character, so you have to alter that as per your need.